# How do I mount these JPEG2000 R, G, B files, with rasterio?

Tags: python, rasterio, jpeg2000

So my problem consists of the trying of getting 3 different .jp2 files - one corresponding to each band R, G, B - and mounting them as a solo RGB file.
I'm using rasterio for the issue, and have followed the following tutorial:
https://towardsdatascience.com/satellite-imagery-access-and-analysis-in-python-jupyter-notebooks-387971ece84b

My code got to this:

```
import os
import geopandas
import rasterio as rio
from PIL import Image

Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 300000000

## RGB Transform

# Image paths: B04 = Red, B03 = Green, B02 = Blue
redPath = "assets/geodata/dump_r2/S2A_MSIL2A_20220512T133231_N0400_R081_T22JCP_20220512T202012.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T22JCP_A035971_20220512T133948/IMG_DATA/R10m/T22JCP_20220512T133231_B04_10m.jp2"
greenPath = "assets/geodata/dump_r2/S2A_MSIL2A_20220512T133231_N0400_R081_T22JCP_20220512T202012.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T22JCP_A035971_20220512T133948/IMG_DATA/R10m/T22JCP_20220512T133231_B03_10m.jp2"
bluePath = "assets/geodata/dump_r2/S2A_MSIL2A_20220512T133231_N0400_R081_T22JCP_20220512T202012.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T22JCP_A035971_20220512T133948/IMG_DATA/R10m/T22JCP_20220512T133231_B02_10m.jp2"

## Bands

"""
redConv = Image.open(redPath)
redConv.save("red.tiff", "TIFF")
greenConv = Image.open(greenPath)
greenConv.save("green.tiff", "TIFF")
blueConv = Image.open(bluePath)
blueConv.save("blue.tiff", "TIFF")
"""
red = rio.open(redPath)
green = rio.open(greenPath)
blue = rio.open(bluePath) 

# Creates RGB file.
rgb = rio.open("RGB.tiff", 'w+', driver="Gtiff", width=red.width, height=red.height, count=3, crs=red.crs, transform=red.transform, dtype=red.dtypes[0])
rgb.write(blue.read(1), 1)
rgb.write(green.read(1), 2)
rgb.write(red.read(1), 3)

print(red.shape)
print(green.shape)
print(blue.shape)

rgb.close()
```

The result however seems to be just gray-scale images, with no channels in reality.
My think-processes were
I. There's something wrong with the drivers, be it the JP2-TIFF conversion or the JP2 reading or the .tiff saving.
II. I don't have enough imagery knowledge, I try opening the "rgb" file through GIMP and it only shows gray-scale images, perhaps there's extra steps I need to take, but as far as I reached, nothing.
III. The rgb.read().shape is [3, 10980, 10980] (like "3 matrices"), I've read other file types (like jpeg) with like matplotlib.image, but it gives a different shape, something like (1980, 1080, 3) ("1 matrix with 3 values in each cell"). But I suppose that's just how .tiff works? Are .tiff even supposed to be visualized?
[image]
*Image opened by gimp*

Meta-data of the image (exiftool)

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.16
File Name                       : RGB.tiff
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 690 MiB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2022:08:24 11:56:03-03:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2022:08:24 11:55:18-03:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2022:08:24 11:56:03-03:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : TIFF
File Type Extension             : tif
MIME Type                       : image/tiff
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Width                     : 10980
Image Height                    : 10980
Bits Per Sample                 : 16 16 16
Compression                     : Uncompressed
Photometric Interpretation      : BlackIsZero
Strip Offsets                   : (Binary data 108116 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Samples Per Pixel               : 3
Rows Per Strip                  : 1
Strip Byte Counts               : (Binary data 65879 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Planar Configuration            : Chunky
Extra Samples                   : Unknown (0 0)
Sample Format                   : Unsigned; Unsigned; Unsigned
Pixel Scale                     : 10 10 0
Model Tie Point                 : 0 0 0 300000 6900040 0
Geo Tiff Version                : 1.1.0
GT Model Type                   : Projected
GT Raster Type                  : Pixel Is Area
GT Citation                     : WGS 84 / UTM zone 22S
Geog Citation                   : WGS 84
Geog Angular Units              : Angular Degree
Projected CS Type               : WGS84 UTM zone 22S
Proj Linear Units               : Linear Meter
Image Size                      : 10980x10980
Megapixels                      : 120.6
```

Comment: Try running `exiftool YOURCREATEDIMAGE.TIF` and then click [edit] and paste the output into your question so we can see exactly what `rasterio` has created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *"Photometric Interpretation"* looks wrong with *"BlackIsZero"*.

Try changing to:

```
rgb = rio.open("RGB.tiff", 'w+', ..., photometric="RGB")
```

and then write the bands in RGB order - rather than BGR.

---

Alternatively, there is a tool called `tiffset` that is installed alongside `libtiff` and you could try changing the *"Photometric Interpretation"* from **MinIsBlack** to **RGB** on your rasterio-generated image like this:

```
tiffset -s 262 2 RGB.TIF
```

Comment: I have added an alternative approach to my answer. Please say how you get on with both.

Comment: So.. I have reasons to believed the first alternative worked. I added the photometric="RGB", changed the bands addition order and on GIMP now it shows 3 bands. I say I have reasons to believe it work, as the image now has colors that move across the whole "spectrum" of the color picker, the previous one didn't, it only slided across gray values on the left. And you can clearly see tonality change on the new one, so I assume it's still dark because it is night time photo I guess. The 2nd alternative gave errors and made the file not openable. https://imgur.com/a/m0EgfNR

Comment: No it did not work. @Mark Setchell
I didn't even stop to think that I could find a colored version from the place i'm downloading (it is still necessary that I'm able to find a way to merge bands).
In the same link I posted in the other comment I posted the colored image and it is pretty vibrant.

Comment: It did actually work. I delved enough to try and find enough information, and apparently that RGB image may not be "clear" or "realistic" perhaps even, however it does seem to actually reflect R, G and B, so it  did work, as I infact have even found work that resulted in similar more dark imagery.
In a nutshell @MarkSetchell first alternative did work.